# React-Native - pass data/function to component

Tags: react-native, components, parent-child

I've got this function inside parent component:

```
toggle   = () => {
    console.log('123');
}
```

This is parent component, and I want pass this function (or be able to use this function actually) in one of my child components (the 3rd in hierarchy).

I'll try to describe it:

```
<ScrollView
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
>
    <Category title={'news'} />
    <Category title={'entertainment'} toggleDropZone={this.toggleDropZone} />
</ScrollView>
```

The `Category` component export a list of items:

```
<Item title="1" />
<item title="2" />
```

So, I want from my `Item` component to use the toggle function. I know the method of using props `toggle={this.toggle}` but I don't want to pass it in each child because its not practical.

There is any other options to pass this data to my child components or alternatively other way to access my main parent from my child component?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you rendering the <Category> component with the renderRow method ?

Comment: No I didn't.. as much as I know - this is method of `ListView`